# Terraform to setup AWS Codepipline Notification Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I have already setup AWS Codepipeline and notification rules manually. On that manual setup pipeline, I have set 4 events to trigger notification on SNS:

- State Execution:

  - Succeeded
  - Failed
- Pipeline Execution:

  - Succeeded
  - Failed

[image]

Now, I am trying to do the same thing with Terraform. But, unable to find the resource in Terraform registry.

How can I find out the Terraform resource to create the Codepipeline Notification Rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CP notifications are set using [aws_codestarnotifications_notification_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codestarnotifications_notification_rule).

For exactly how to set `event_type_ids`  up you have to refer to AWS docs:

- [Events for notification rules on pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/concepts.html#events-ref-pipeline)